# i want to change the label when the buttonn is clicked in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am using discord_buttons_plugin to create buttons but i am not able to edit the button by its custom id! Is there any way to use custom_id to edit the button in @button.click, Here's My code:

```
from discord_buttons_plugin import *
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
buttons = ButtonsClient(client)
   
@client.command()
async def btn(ctx)
await buttons.send(
     channel = ctx.channel.id,
      components = [
            ActionRow([
                Button(

                    style = ButtonType().Secondary,
                    label = "_",
                    custom_id = "b1",

                )
            ])
        ]
    )
```

I tried to change the button label by this:

```
   @buttton.click
   async def b1():
    Button.b1(label="X")
```

But it don't works and gives interaction error in discord. I there any way to change the button by this way using custom id...

Comment: Maybe you can create a new Action row? Then once the button is clicked, you can edit the message sent by changing the components to the new action row (e.g. components=[action_row] is changed to components=[new_action_row) on the message your bot sent.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's possible to edit a message with changed buttons in this library. If you want that functionality, you can just use discord.py, since they added buttons and more in their (unstable) 2.0.0 Version.